# How do I measure the Networking time when executing a query against MongoDB in Nodejs (using mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, database-performance

I have a couple of microservices which are connecting to a single instance of MongoDB. The microservices are in Nodejs (express + mongoose) and everything is in a `docker-compose` file and is deployed using `Docker-Swarm`. What I need is to measure different parts of execution time for `findOne` method (not the whole HTTP request) of a mongoose model. When I measure the total execution time sometimes I even get values as high as 250ms or 400ms (with the high load in the system) and sometimes I get values like 10ms or 25ms. But when I use `explain` with mongo (in NodeJS) it tells me the query took 0 - 3 ms. I suspect the problem is with docker-swarm networking but I don't know how I can measure what that 400ms is built up of. For example, I'd like to know how much time it took start talking to mongo or vice-versa.

I guess I can use `tcpdump` and look at traces and their timestamps (not sure if it works). I guess I'm looking for something simpler, hopefully in Node.js.

**Clarify:**
I am already measuring many time spans in the server. The one I'm currently looking for is:

when I execute `await MongooseModel.findOne({name:'vahid'})`, how much time it takes for this request to go from node to mongo (not the time it takes the query to be executed on mongo)?

Answer (score 0):

The driver does not track network i/o time separately from query execution time. You could try:

- examining round-trip time on server description (this is averaged and is intended to smooth out latency spikes)
- enabling query logging on the server side and seeing if that gives timing information

Comment: The mongodb is on localhost. I try query logging but doubt it works